# How to delete 1000s of emails before 2020-03-02?

Tags: 18.04, email-client

- I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Alpine 2.21. I opened a terminal to Ubuntu shell via Putty.
- I have root access via sudo.
- I tried a perl script called `mbox-purge.pl` from 2017 (which worked then) to purge 1000s of emails before March 3, 2020 but I'm missing a Perl module called `RS::Handy` and I cannot find a .tar.gz file to download and install RS::Handy so mbox-purge.pl doesn't work. And RS::Handy is not part of cpan currently, i.e. `cpanm` cannot find it.
- Email errors are the result of a cron job that runs every 10 minutes.
- My emails seem to be stored in a single file in /var/spool/USERNAME.
- I got nothing after searching Askubuntu or googling.

How do I delete all these extra cron job errors from my email?

Thank you.

Comment: Try the command line `mail`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have no man entry for `mail`.

Comment: If the executable `/usr/bin/mail.mailutils` does not exist in your system, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install mailutils`... 

`mail` will be an alias for `mail.mailutils`...